# sum of values in a column corresponding to first and last occurrence of a number in another column - matlab

Tags: matlab

```
a = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]';
```

What is the quickest way to sum the values in column 2 that correspond to the first and last occurrence of each number in column 1?

The desired output:

```
1  5
2  13
3  21
```

EDIT: The result should be the same if the numbers in column 1 are ordered differently.

```
a = [2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]';

    2  5
    1  13
    3  21
```

Comment: Does column 1 always contain positive integers?

Comment: @Luis Mendo: Yes.

Comment: Are those integer values always contiguously grouped as in the example?

Comment: No, it varies. Sometimes it is [1 2 3] sometimes [2 1 3 4], etc

Comment: But can first column be  for example `[1 1 2 2 2 1 1 3 3 3].'`? Note the `1`'s are in two groups

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Yes, they are always contiguous, so [1 1 2 2 1 1 3 3 3] does not happen

Comment: Maybe edit those two restrictions into the question for future reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) as follows. Not sure how fast it is, especially because it uses a custom anonymous function:

```
[u, ~, v] = unique(a(:,1), 'stable');
s = accumarray(v, a(:,2), [], @(x) x(1)+x(end));
result = [u s];
```

If the values in the first column of `a` are always in contiguous groups, the following approach can be used as well:

```
ind_diff = find(diff(a(:,1))~=0);
ind_first = [1; ind_diff+1];
ind_last = [ind_diff; size(a,1)];
s = a(ind_first,2) + a(ind_last,2);
result = [unique(a(:,1), 'stable') s];
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work with the example above. However when column 1 is [2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3] I get a different result

Comment: It should be [2 5; 1 13; 3 21], since I just switched the ones with the twos in column 1, but column 2 remained the same

Comment: So column 1 in the result is insensitive to actual values in column 1 of `a`? Please include that as a second example in the question

Comment: Glad to help! :-)